# Veeery slow DNS propagation

Tags: dns, dreamhost, propagation

[image]tree days ago i've changed the nameservers for a website through my italian registar (http://www.ormag.net/) from Dreamhost to Digital Ocean.
The website is: [www.marchespettacolo.it](http://www.marchespettacolo.it).

I know that the normal time to wait for propagation is 72h but this time is already passed and almost everyone can see the website but not me and my client that is actually quite angry about that.

There is some other things that i can DO/CHECK/VERIFY to ensure that everithing is fine and we have just to wait or there are the possibilities that i've done something wrong?

Thhanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something went wrong with your new configuration. under NS1.DIGITALOCEAN.COM there is currently no A record for this domain available. you can check this with http://en.dnstools.ch/dns-nameserver.html or with the dig-command when you're in front of a linux / mac pc.
open a terminal and try: dig A www.marchespettacolo.it @ns1.digitalocean.com

**EDIT:**
www.marchespettacolo.it is a subdomain of marchespettacolo.it (which already points to 82.196.7.250). you need to make a seperate A or CNAME record for that.

Comment: How the A and CNAME ercord should look like?

Comment: I don't know how your control panel looks like. Try sth like: www.marchespettacolo.it CNAME marchespettacolo.it

Comment: I've two fields when i choose add a new CNAME: NAME and HOSTNAME (should finish wth a dot). Actually i've set it as: marchespettacolo.it | www.marchespettacolo.it.
Sounds good?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-a-host-name-with-digitalocean skip to the CNAME part. you can check it with the command: dig CNAME www.marchespettacolo.it @ns1.digitalocean.com

Comment: Wooooooo. Got it! Thaaanks man! Sometime the solution is under your nose and actually impossible to be seen! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

try nslookup  8.8.8.8,
its the google public domain ip address, it will cache new IP address for your domain,
you can try this method for all public domains, most of the peoples uses public domains for dns resolution,